# Hide dropdown when adding new row in JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

In my Application, I can add a new row by clicking on the '+' sign.
When clicked on '+' sign new row got created but I want some particular field to be hidden when clicking on '+' sign and those hidden fields will be shown by satisfying some conditions. How can I achieve this feature when creating the new row?

[image: Screenshot of the sample]
Code for adding new row:

```
$("#addRow").click(function() {
    openSearchdiv = true;
    $("#searchTable").append('
<tr>
   <td>
      <select class="lovs" id="field" >
         <option value="select"></option>
         <option value="rowid_system">Source System Name</option>
         <option value="rule_num">Rule No</option>
      </select>
   </td>
   <td>
      <select class="lovs" id="operator">
         <option value="EQUAL">EQUAL</option>
         <option value="NOT EQUAL">NOT EQUAL</option>
      </select>
   </td>
   <td></td>
   <td>
      <select class="lovs" id="function">
         <option value="AND">AND</option>
      </select>
   </td>
   <td align="center"><img alt="" title="Delete" id="deleteRow" src="/MatchMergeAPI_POC/img/minus.png" style="height:15px;width:15px;"></td>
</tr>');
});
```

When the table first loaded I am hiding the value drop down. And it is visible by clicking on the field name. So I want this behavior to be the same when clicked on '+' sign. Presently I am just putting  as blank when appending the table row.

Populating Dropdown values:

```
$("#searchTable").on('click','#field',function(){
        //alert('hi');
        //var showSpan = false;
        var showHide = false;
        var showRule = false;
        var srcNameInd = false;
        var src=null;

        $("#searchTable tbody >tr").each(function()
                {
                    $("td > *",this).each(function() 
                        {
                            if (this.nodeName == "SELECT") {
                                if ($(this).attr("id") == "field") {

                                    field = $(this).val();

                                    if(field=="rowid_system" )
                                    {
                                        showHide=true;  

                                        console.log('rowid_system');

                                        //populate value for source name
                                        //$("#field").on('click',function(){
                                            //alert('ajax call');
                                            $.ajax({
                                                url: contextPath+"/getSourceName/ORG",
                                                datatype: "JSON",
                                                type: "Get",
                                                contentType : "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                                                success: function(data)
                                                {
                                                    srcName.populateSrcName(
                                                        data,
                                                        $('#srcName')

                                                    );
                                                }                                         

                                            });
```

Answer (score 0):

You could hide the select of the last row you've added to the table after the append line, like :

```
$("#searchTable tr:last select").hide();
```

Or you could add inline style while appending like :

```
$("#searchTable").append('<tr><td><select style="display:none" class="lovs" id="fi...');
```

You could also add a class that hides the field then remove it when you want to show it again :

```
.hide{
     display: none;
}

$("#searchTable").append('<tr><td><select class="lovs hide" id="fi...');
```

And try to use event delegation on the click like :

```
$('body').on('click', '#addRow', function() {
    //Your flow here
});
```

Comment: I can hide the value drop down by putting 'style="display:none" ' in each drop down. Now what I want is that the hidden drop down will be visible when choosing the field value.It is working when the "#searchTable" loaded but not working when clicking on '+' sign.

Comment: The `+` sign you mean `#addRow` ?

Comment: Yes '+' sign is for '#addRow'

Comment: I did the change by adding 'style="display:none"'. But It only hides the drop down.I want to displaythose drop down when click on field options.

Comment: Have you tried the event delegation I suggest in my update? Please add the HTML code so we can help.

Comment: When I debug in UI the dropdown value is populating but the value dropdown field is not displayed.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177073/discussion-between-zakaria-acharki-and-arindam-kotal).

Comment: I can see dropdown value got changed for Value field depending on field value. But When I click '+' button it is only reflected in the first row. Any clue will be helpful.

Comment: Please add the full code here  https://jsfiddle.net/z_acharki/jnwrc5ay/817/ and click update and then copy/send me the new generate link

Comment: Then you should give me the new link to the updated one